# How to remove all consonants and print vowels in a list

Tags: python-2.7, containers

Here is my code:

```
#Alphabet class
class Alphabet(object):

        def __init__(self, s):
            self.s = s

        def __str__(self):
            return "Before: " + str(self.s)


#Define your Vowels class here
class Vowels:
        def __init__(self,vowelList):
                self.vowelList = vowelList

        def __str__(self):
                return "Invoking the method in Vowels by passing the Alphabet object\nAfter: " + str(vowelList)

        def addVowels(self,a_obj):
                for letter in a_obj:
                    if letter in 'aeiou':
                        vowelList.append(letter)
                        l = ','.join(vowelList)

a1 = Alphabet('A,B,C,E,I')
print a1
b = Vowels(a1)
b.addVowels(a1)
print (a2)
```

Right now, all it is printing is "Before: A,B,C,E,I", but I am trying to take a string of letters separated by commas (i.e. a_obj), extract the vowels from the string, then append the result to a list. I have looked at other answers regarding finding and printing only the vowels, which is why I have the for loop and if statement in addVowels, but no luck. Just to note,Vowels is supposed to be a container class for Alphabet.

When trying to get the output...the below code gives me

```
a1 = Alphabet('A,B,C,E,I')
print a1
a2 = Vowels(a1)
print a2
```

ouput:

```
Before: A,B,C,E,I
Invoking the method in Vowels by passing the Alphabet object
After: []
```

it seems like it isn't passing the letters from Alphabet...

Answer (score 0):

You can create the list and get rid of the commas in one line by using `split`.

```
>>> "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j".split(",")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

From there you can remove the consonants by only keeping the vowels.
You can use a for loop:

```
letterList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
vowelList = []

for letter in letterList:
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        vowelList.append(letter)
```

Or you can use list comprehension:

```
letterList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
vowelList = [letter for letter in letterList if letter in 'aeiou']
```

Example of how this would work for your code:

```
class Vowels(object):
    def __init__(self, vowelList):
        self.vowelList = vowelList

        lettersList = self.vowelList.s.split(",")
        self.vowelList = [letter for letter in self.lettersList if letter in 'aeiou']
```

Comment: how would I call Vowels using the object given in Alphabet?

Comment: The way you did it is ok: `a1 = Alphabet('A,B,C,E,I')` and `b = Vowels(a1)`

Comment: Instead of having `addVowels` function you should do that stuff in the `__init__`

Comment: see bottom of my question, i added a problem I am getting now

Comment: also in the addVowels method i am getting that a_obj is not iterable

Comment: Rewrite your code to use what I commented! You can access the string by `self.vowelList.s` in the Vowels class

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code, and it works for me.

```
def getVowels(text):

vowel_letters = []
vowel_list = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U',]

for vowels in text:
    if vowels in vowel_list:
        vowel_letters.append(vowels)

return vowel_letters

print(getVowels('Hi, How are you today!'))
## Output: ['i', 'o', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'o', 'a']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)